# Angular Routing to HTML Files Not Working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Angular learning through videos. I got stuck in this routing part of my code.

index.html

```
<header id="top" class="header">
    <div class="text-vertical-center bg-color" ng-controller="HeaderController">
        <h1 class="animated fadeInLeft">SORTIFY</h1>
        <h3 class="animated fadeInUp">Your Personal Music Assistant</h3>
        <br>
          <a href="#music" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" >Check out Music</a>
          <a href="#genre" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Genrify your Songs</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('sortify', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$httpProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
function($httpProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
    .state('music', {
    url: 'music',
    templateUrl: 'music.html',
  });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index');
}]);
```

This is my folder structure:

[image]

I tried many ways but am still failing, have a look!!

**EDIT**
Here is a view of the UI

[image]

Comment: you can use ui-sref="statename" instead of href in anchor tag of your header

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is causing your problem but try like this:

```
<a href="#/music" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" >Check out Music</a>
```

and in the config file:

```
.state('music', {
url: '/music',
templateUrl: 'music.html',
```

});

PS. Do you have `<div ui-view></div>` somewhere on your app?

Comment: I added that but still of no use, maybe I am doing some silly mistake.

Comment: See whats happening in the Console and post the errors if there are some, also provide more code so if there is 'silly' mistake someone will spot it.

Comment: angular-route.min.js:7 -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined

Comment: angular.js:38 -> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: so make sure you referenced ui-router in your index.html and Injected on your app module